# Will I get banned or blocked for running a diagnostic app?

Tags: ping, connection, ddos, testing

This may seem like a simple question. Hopefully it will have a simple answer.

I run an internet radio station. There are 3 machines.

1. Music source client
2. Stage server
3. Master server (relays the signal from the stage server to our listeners)

Recently there have been some drop outs, I suspect internet quality is to blame.

https://code.google.com/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/

I want to install this utility on 1 and 2 above to ping a) Google and b) the next machine in the chain every 5 seconds to see who drops what and when.

Not being classically trained, I want to know the below...

Is this best practice? Or will I get in trouble from google or my ISP?

I don't want to get caught in some DDOS defense on some firewall somewhere and cause more issues for myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Pings alone will not get you in trouble, they are a fairly basic part of the connectivity toolkit, and are not usually seen as an attack. That seems to make handshakes of some sort, possibly tcp, possibly http.. neither are threats at one every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a radio station the [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_delay_variation) and [packet loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss) should be minimized. To monitor this you can use [SmokePing](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/). For more tools take a look on the [CAIDA](http://www.caida.org/tools/taxonomy/perf2taxonomy.xml) site.

Comment: Is there a windows package for SmokePing? or equivalent?

Edit: found it http://dev.pulsed.net/wp/?p=31

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective this is way too low traffic to be considered a DDOS.
Most likely nobody will even notice  what you are doing.

But consider this:
- Do you have full control/ownership of the machines involved ? If not you may need approval of the rightful owner.
- This sort of test doesn't mean much in regards to your problem. See Mircea's answer for better tools for the job.

Comment: Thanks. Will do, and yes I control machines 1 & 2.